# WPF datagrid - How to set cell background colour based on value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'd like to set datagrid cell background colour based on its value

What I understand is normally, I would need to create a class
Then { get: set: } data property, bind data collection to datagrid itemsource, finally use datatrigger to set background color

However, in my scenario, data is dynamic instead of static from column 4
(starting from column 'Data001' in below example screenshot)

Which means,

1. number of columns is dynamic;
2. column header name is dynamic;

[image]

So I didn't end up creating data class, instead I put data into a dictionary first

And then from dictionary into datatable, convert datatable into dataview and finally bind to ItemsSource.

Something like below:

```cs
//viewModel
var dtCalcResult = new DataTable();
DtView = dtCalcResult.AsDataView();
 
//xaml
<DataGrid 
            x:Name="dtgdTest" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="10" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding DtView}"
            RowHeight="16"
            FrozenColumnCount="3"
            ColumnHeaderHeight="24"
            EnableRowVirtualization="True"
            EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
            Loaded="dtgdTest_Load"
            >
```

Now my question is how to assign cell background colour by its value?

I have tried to work with the following way ->

Use GetCellContent() to get cell value, then set background colour base on value

Something like this:

```cs
                // GET ROW COUNT
                var rowCount = targetDataGrid.Items.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
                {
                    // GET ROW OBJECT
                    var row = targetDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;

                    if (row == null)
                    {
                        // USE ScrollIntoView() TO THAT ROW
                        targetDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
                        targetDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(targetDataGrid.Items[i]);
                        // TRY TO GET OBJECT AGAIN
                        row = targetDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;
                    }
 
                    // GET COLUMN COUNT
                    var columnCount = targetDataGrid.Columns.Count;
                    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; ++j)
                    {
                        // GET CELL OBJECT
                        var elem = targetDataGrid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(row);

                        if (elem == null)
                        {
                            // USE ScrollIntoView() TO THAT COLUMN
                            targetDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
                            targetDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(targetDataGrid.Columns[j]);
                            // TRY TO GET OBJECT AGAIN
                            elem = targetDataGrid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(row);
                        }
 
                        // SET BACKGROUND COLOUR
                        DataGridCell cell = elem.Parent as DataGridCell;
                        string colHeader = targetDataGrid.Columns[j].Header.ToString();
                        string cellData = _viewModel.DictColNameAndValues[colHeader][i];
                        //float actHour = _viewModel.DictValueLists_ActHour[colHeader][i];
 
                        if (8 < float.Parse(cellData))
                        {
                            cell.Background = Brushes.Green;
 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.Background = Brushes.White;
                        }
```

With above, the result is:

1. Getting error, after ScrollIntoView(), still cannot get cell value, returns null;
2. While cells without an error, background colour assignment is wrong; (like colour appears to incorrect cells)
3. Once I scroll in view, the assigned colour will shift position;
4. When I load ~1k+ columns, pagination becomes super slow and lag (I felt this one probably need to create a separate thread to ask)

Something like this:
[image]

If datagrid is not the best way to do this, is there any other user control or method to archive my goal? (to be able to assign cell background colour when having dynamic columns)

I can give it a try if there's any as long as the package license is free to publish

Thanks!

---

*2022-Oct30 Update*

Follow up question to @Siegfried.V answer:

Here hopefully I made a better example which closer to my real scenario:

[image]

It can show that starting from column-4, column names are all dates

The range of dates is also going to be dynamic populated depending on the data source pulled each time. Which means I cannot bind with any static properties unlike first three columns(Name, Pref and Age)

Answer (score 0):

The following Xaml snippet was copied/pasted from production code.
Where the key parts are the bound "model" `PlanningComplete` properties in the `<Style.Triggers>`:

```
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="2"
                      x:Name="dataGrid"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}"
                      PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown"
                      IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PlanningComplete}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PlanningComplete}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EventName1}"
                                        Header="{Binding Source={x:Static rmc:AppLocalization.Event}}" 
                                        Width="200"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EventName2}"
                                        Width="80"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EventDate,Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToLongStringConverter}}"
                                        Header="{Binding Source={x:Static rmc:AppLocalization.Date}}" 
                                        Width="{Binding Source={x:Static rmc:AppConstants.DataGridColumnWidthDateTime}}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LocationName1}"
                                        Header="{Binding Source={x:Static rmc:AppLocalization.EventLocation}}" 
                                        Width="190*" MinWidth="190"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in xaml as Stefan offered (but if I am not mistaken his code is to colour one full row), but personally I prefer using converters, so you could reuse the code in all the project, or even better in all solution, putting converters in an external library :

XAML : (NameSpace and assembly at your choice)

```
<Window x:Class="V_CN.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:`NameSpace`;assembly=`YourAssembly`"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="YourTitle" >
    

<Window.Resources>
    <converters:ColoringAgeConverter x:Key="coloringAgeConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Your column :

```
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path="Age" Converter="{StaticResource coloringAgeConverter}"}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Then the converter itself :

```
public class ColoringAgeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

    {
        int valInt = Int32.Parse(value.ToString());
        switch (valInt)
        {
            case 1: return "#F0FFE4B5";
            case 2: return "#4000FFFF";
            case 3: return "#407FFF00";
            case 4: return "#907FCC00";
            case 5: return "#C07FCC00";
            case 6: return "#FF0FFF00";
            default: return "#FFFFFFFF";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with using a colour switch converter.

Comment: For the column part, `Binding Path="Age"` as you mentioned as in example, how should I handle if my data column binding is dynamic instead of static like `Age` for each time.

Comment: @Joshua.S it's exactly the same. I guess for you it is working for Age, not for others, this is because your biding is not working (You can check it in debug mode, see if the converter is executed when you modify the column). On how to make the binding, you can find many tutorials/links. Here is an explaination I made for binding TabControl, this is the same idea for datagrid : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255609/running-the-tabcontrol-contenttemplate-within-the-tabcontrol/74256109?noredirect=1#comment131099605_74256109

Comment: I have just added a bit more detail explain up in my question post. Hope that can help with what I meant , basically any columns beyond first three would need to be dynamically populated. So I am not sure how I can bind in that situation, thanks!

Comment: @Joshua.S the problem is you don't know how biding works. Please, read the link I gave you, there I explained minimum requirements so the binding will work. Once you understood, all will work perfectly. DId you check that the converter was executed whn you edit a value?